# Problem updating i3

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, i3-wm

I have a problem with updating i3-wm

When I type

```
i3 --moreversion 2>&- || i3 --version
```

I get

```
Binary i3 version:  4.7.2 (2014-01-23, branch "tags/4.7.2") © 2009-2013 Michael Stapelberg and contributors
Running i3 version: 4.7.2 (2014-01-23, branch "tags/4.7.2") (pid 1889)

The i3 binary you just called: /usr/bin/i3
The i3 binary you are running: i3
```

So I'm on 4.7.2 version, and I checked, that version is from last year, newest is 4.10.3.

However when I apt-get update and upgrade nothing gets upgraded, and I tried

```
~/Downloads/i3-4.10.3$ sudo apt-get install i3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
i3 is already the newest version.
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 4.10.3 isn't in the Ubuntu repositories for Trusty. You need Wily for that or simpler with the following steps to add an additionally repository:

```
sudo -i
echo "deb http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ $(lsb_release -c -s) universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install sur5r-keyring
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
exit        # to leave the root shell
```

<sub>[Source](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html)</sub>

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a bunch. However, if you have some time, could you please explain your line of thought to have found this solution. I'm kind of new on Ubuntu and I'd like to be able to find out that stuff on my own rather than asking everytime. Anyway, fixed so thanks.

Comment: Below the commands is the link. :)

Comment: @Mr.Smith: what he means is: look at the little orange "Source"!  ;-)